# Welcoming museum guests

Tags: phrase-requests

I have began working at a museum in which we receive many Japanese tourists. I have minimal experience in the Japanese language and am looking for a phrase I can use to welcome guests after they have purchased tickets. If a different phrase is needed to welcome a singular guest versus a group of guests, I would like to know both.

Additionally, if there are any phrases that pop into mind for working with Japanese tourists, those would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

if you simply want to say "Welcome to X Museum" the simplest phrase is

"X Museum e yookoso."

If you want to say something more flowery, you could follow up by saying "Please take your time and enjoy yourselves."  which is

"Go yukkuri tanoshinde kudasai."

keep in mind that the "double o" simply means to hold that long o sound for twice as long, it does NOT mean to make an "u" sound. Similarly, the "double k" is the notation meaning "put a slight pause before uttering the "ku" sound. If you are uncertain of the proper sound, you ought to be able to find online resources to help you say these words correctly.

Comment: I am having trouble finding "yookoso" in my dictionary. Could you tell me a form of this word I could look up?

Comment: It's youkoso, i.e 良う こそ.

Comment: @NoahRoseLedesma It's written ようこそ but it's pronounced ヨーコソ.  The "yookoso" romanization is based on the pronunciation, while the "youkoso" romanization is based on the Japanese spelling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking something like

> <Museum name> へご[来館]{らい・かん}いただき(まして)まことにありがとうございます。

Which means "Thank you for coming to the museum".

although I'm not sure if that would be overly polite.